# What is the best solution for checking if a logged-in user's account still matches or exists from the database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it a good practice if every time when a logged-in user refreshes or re-enters the site, it will check from the database if that account still exists or matches from the database without sacrificing the performance of the site?

What I wanted to do is that for every activity that a logged-in user do (even navigating pages that has authentication), it will re-authenticate the account if the credentials (such as username and password) still matches from the database. What would be the best solution to address this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a session and check it in every relevant page.
Set a timeout if required, and if login is time sensitive, eg like banks where inactivity logs you out in X mins (usually 5 or 10) then you'll need persistence like a DB table or other like Redis where you can more easily manage user logins with activity timestamps etc.

Regarding when an account is closed, this action should flush the sessions anyway, so logout or account close actions would invoke the same thing in terms of them not being logged in anymore.

Then if they hit something really sensitive you can ask them for their password again and create a new session key. Like in amazon you can view certain things in your account even after some inactivity period, but then some things require password confirmation, like viewing personal data etc.

If performance of the site is a concern, then this is likely not the bottleneck. Database queries and session verification are basic requirements that can't be avoided.

If such things are noticeably slow, look at better code (or a framework if it'd suit) or cache if you don't already have it.